# rails bootstrap-switch, cannot display toggled status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-switch

i know this question had been asked so many times but despite researching for the past 2 days i still can't get the solution.

currently i implemented bootstrap-switch into my rails apps. after toggling from off to on, the database updated the boolean value correctly.

unfortunately upon visited back to the page with bootstrap-switch, it shows "OFF" and not the saved toggled status "ON".

what should i do so it display the correct status every time it is toggled?

really really appreciated with thanks on any help..

### rails view

```
    <%= form_for([:admin, type], remote: true, url: admin_update_ot_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
          <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, :value => @product.id, :id => "pid" %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :option_type_id, :value => type.id, :class => "tid" %> 
          <%= f.check_box :hidden, id: "bootstrapswitch", 'data-type' => type.id %> 
      </div>
        <%= f.submit "update option type" %>
    <% end %>
```

### option_type.js.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
$("[id='bootstrapswitch']").bootstrapSwitch()
```

### option_type.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

$('.edit_option_type input[type=submit]').remove();
$('.edit_option_type input[type=checkbox]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    var product_id = $("#pid").val();
    var option_type_id = $(this).data('type');
    console.log(option_type_id);


    if (state == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/admin/update_ot",
            data: {option_type: {product_id: product_id, option_type_id: option_type_id, hidden: 1}}
            });
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/admin/update_ot",
            data: {option_type: {product_id: product_id, option_type_id: option_type_id, hidden: 0}}
            });
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Could you add some necessary / relevant code snippet so someone can understand your problem and proffer a good solution

Comment: updated as per request.. after opening new page, even if the "ON" state was toggled and saved in database, reopening the page in new tab still display the "OFF" state.

Comment: I wanted to ask how you get in the field f.checkbox the value from the database (:admin.hidden) ? Thanks a lot